# Using File I/O in Java

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to create a pet project for the summer, which requires a large amount of information. I think the best way to do this would be to store all the data in a text file, and proceed to pull the necessary information from that file when it's called upon. My question, though, is how to pull specific sets of information, and then proceed to store parts of that into an array perhaps or some other data structure which would allow for that to be more easily accessed during the execution of the program. The text file would have hundreds (if not thousands) of "sets" of data, and each "set" will have multiple parts. For example,

```
ID001 Name Data1 Data2 Data3 TypeData
```

Where ID001 would just be an index, the name would be a string, the three "Data" would be integers, and the TypeData would be a String (for example). What is the best way to go about taking all that information (there'll actually be more data per "set" but for simplicity's sake let's go with just this) and separating it so each part is usable by a different part of the program? Is this even the right way to go about doing something like this? I was originally imagining something along the lines of a spreadsheet but I don't know how to use something quite like that as I/O for a program.

Comment: Anything wrong with java.util.Scanner?

Comment: I was imagining Scanner would work, but again I don't know how to separate each part of the data set into individual pieces of usable data.

Comment: If you want to store structured data in a text file, perhaps you should consider using XML.

Comment: That seems like the obvious answer now that I think about it, not sure why I never thought of it before.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a database?

Comment: It needs to be offline, and as a beginning programmer I have little to no experience in using a database in conjunction with a java program.

Comment: If the pet project is to learn about really useful stuff, I'd strongly recommend grabbing an open source database like PostgreSQL or HSQLDB and getting running with it. If you want to muck about with spreadsheet type stuff, there's an apache library called POI that can read and write Excel directly. Of course, File IO is also really useful stuff, too. (edit - I just realised how old this question is. I hope your pet project went well!!)

Comment: JAXB is an easy way to load/save your data from/to xml.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way of reading a file and getting just the "chunks":

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanXan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can take a look at the [Java Scanner Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) for other ideas.